# DirectX crash when running fxc.exe within tracker.exe, -1073741819 error from msbuild

Tags: msbuild, shader

When the following command is run from msbuild:

```
D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe" /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll /i D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release /r D:\PROJECTS\VISUALSTUDIOPROJECTS\THOR\MAIN\SBC\APP\CORE\EXECUI\LIBS.LIVELIB\BRIGHTNESSHISTOGRAM.HLSL /c C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  /nologo /E"BrightnessHistogram" /T cs_5_0 /Fh "x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h" /Vn "g_BrightnessHistogram" BrightnessHistogram.hlsl
```

DirectX crashes (receive a pop-up window), and msbuild returns the error code `-1073741819`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1129,5): error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
```

Note that if the fxc.exe command is run stand-alone it is successful.

Further investigation shows that procmon.exe records the following sequence just after the .h file is generated SUCCESSFULLY. Note all the buffer overflows. For whatever reason, there is not enough buffer space provided for the QueryNameInformationFile operations. So, it appears that fxc.exe is failing because it is not betting the correct DLL names it needs. This is a Windows 10 system, running Visual Studio 2012. **This system worked fine for quite some time, then something happened to make it stop working.**

```
Time of Day Process Name    PID Operation   Path    Result  Detail
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,487, Length: 3
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,490, Length: 2
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,492, Length: 3
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,495, Length: 2
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,497, Length: 3
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,500, Length: 2
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,502, Length: 3
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    WriteFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS Offset: 11,505, Length: 6
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    CloseFile   D:\Projects\VisualStudioProjects\Thor\Release\2.52\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h   SUCCESS 
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  SUCCESS Name: \Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager   REPARSE Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager   SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    RegSetInfoKey   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SESSION MANAGER   SUCCESS KeySetInformationClass: KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SESSION MANAGER\ResourcePolicies  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 24
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SESSION MANAGER   SUCCESS 
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  SUCCESS Name: \Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\System32\locale.nls  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Windo
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\1033\FileTrackerUI.dll    BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Windo
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\Globalization\Sorting\SortDefault.nls    BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Windo
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Dev\ms\kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Dev\m
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Windo
20:04.3 fxc.exe 4228    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll   BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \Windo
```

I have another system, which is a Windows 7 system, that will compile the same code just fine. Here is the output from procmon for the same sequence on the Windows 7 system. Note there are no buffer overflows. Also note that after the .h file is created, this working sequence shows that the fxc.read.1.tlog and fxc.write.1.tlog  files are accessed (whereas not so in the broken sequence.) Note that I do NOT think this is a Windows 10 issue.

```
Time of Day Process Name    PID Operation   Path    Result  Detail
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,474, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,476, Length: 3, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,479, Length: 8, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,487, Length: 3, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,490, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,492, Length: 3, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,495, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,497, Length: 3, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,500, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,502, Length: 3, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Offset: 11,505, Length: 6, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 12072, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.0000000
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS CreationTime: 6/2/2016 7:41:57 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, ChangeTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, FileAttributes: D
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS CreationTime: 6/2/2016 7:41:57 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, ChangeTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:57 AM, FileAttributes: D
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release  SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   ReadFile    C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryStandardInformationFile    C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS AllocationSize: 8,192, EndOfFile: 6,228, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Offset: 6,228, Length: 396, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Offset: 6,624, Length: 164, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\BrightnessHistogram.hlsl SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\BrightnessHistogram.hlsl SUCCESS CreationTime: 10/6/2015 11:01:23 AM, LastAccessTime: 10/6/2015 11:01:23 AM, LastWriteTime: 10/6/2015 11:01:23 AM, ChangeTime: 10/6/2015 11:01:23 AM, AllocationSize: 4096, EndOfFile: 2326, FileAttributes: A
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\BrightnessHistogram.hlsl SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Offset: 6,788, Length: 162, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe SUCCESS CreationTime: 7/25/2012 7:25:38 PM, LastAccessTime: 10/6/2015 10:26:10 AM, LastWriteTime: 7/25/2012 7:25:38 PM, ChangeTime: 11/23/2015 9:45:38 AM, AllocationSize: 94208, EndOfFile: 94152, FileAttributes: A
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS Offset: 6,950, Length: 114, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.read.1.tlog  SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   ReadFile    C:  SUCCESS Offset: 48,697,344, Length: 96, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   ReadFile    C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 2, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryStandardInformationFile    C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS AllocationSize: 8,192, EndOfFile: 5,018, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS Offset: 5,018, Length: 396, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS Offset: 5,414, Length: 164, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CreateFile  C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS CreationTime: 1/5/2017 9:00:09 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/9/2017 11:54:46 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/10/2017 1:20:47 PM, ChangeTime: 1/10/2017 1:20:47 PM, AllocationSize: 12288, EndOfFile: 11511, FileAttributes: A
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\BrightnessHistogram.h    SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   WriteFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS Offset: 5,578, Length: 180, Priority: Normal
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   CloseFile   C:\Projects\Thor\Main\sbc\app\core\ExecUI\Libs.LiveLib\x64\Release\fxc.write.1.tlog SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize    SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   RegSetInfoKey   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize    SUCCESS KeySetInformationClass: KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize\DisableMetaFiles   NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 20
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   RegCloseKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize    SUCCESS 
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 10292, User Time: 0.0468003, Kernel Time: 0.3588023
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll    SUCCESS Name: \Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe SUCCESS Name: \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll  SUCCESS Name: \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll   SUCCESS Name: \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\8E4EA70A-6128-4B57-BD3F-8E9E0F0DA6BB\COM_Sensor.dll    SUCCESS Name: \Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\8E4EA70A-6128-4B57-BD3F-8E9E0F0DA6BB\COM_Sensor.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\8E4EA70A-6128-4B57-BD3F-8E9E0F0DA6BB\OS_Plugin.dll SUCCESS Name: \Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\8E4EA70A-6128-4B57-BD3F-8E9E0F0DA6BB\OS_Plugin.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AME_SmtpSensor.dll    SUCCESS Name: \Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AME_SmtpSensor.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AME_OutlookSensor.dll SUCCESS Name: \Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AME_OutlookSensor.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AE_MailSensor_Plugin.dll  SUCCESS Name: \Program Files\DGAgent\plugins\09D849B6-32D3-4A40-85EE-6B84BA29E35B\AE_MailSensor_Plugin.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DgApi.dll   SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\DgApi.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll    SUCCESS Name: \Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll    SUCCESS Name: \Windows\System32\wow64win.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll   SUCCESS Name: \Windows\System32\wow64.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll   SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll
20:47.1 fxc.exe 12192   QueryNameInformationFile    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll SUCCESS Name: \Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me it was related to dgagent.exe **and not** to VS, .NET tools, environment variables, win10, etc.
Almost sure this is the same issue.

If you can, uninstall Digital Guardian agent. If not, contact your IT department and ask them to fix it.

-1073741819 is 0xC0000005 which is ACCESS_VIOLATION exception.